# Pesquisa dinâmica para seleção

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho a necessidade de em uma campo text ao clicar na tecla F2 abrir uma janela de consulta e ao selecionar o funcionário levar código do mesmo para o campo text.

Teria alguma biblioteca no jquery ou outra solução?

Comment: Pode começar com a função [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Até ai eu sei chamar uma janela de consulta, mais não sei como retornar o valor da consulta para o campo text.

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta e seja mais claro em suas necessidades. Poste os códigos que já fez e detalhe exatamente o que o código deve fazer.

Answer (score 0):

As teclas de função(F1, F2, F3, F4...) geralmente já são usadas para determinadas funções do browser, dessa forma, não é possível monitorá-las. Caso queira capturar outra tecla qualquer você pode simplesmente usar o código abaixo:

```
  function teclaPressionada(){
     alert("tecla" + event.keyCode);
  }
document.onkeypress = tecla;
```

Assim você descobrirá o código da tecla ao pressionar qualquer tecla com a página `html` aberta. Após isso é so montar a chamada a função que deseja

Comment: Sim até ai sei, mais como fazer que ao selecionar o funcionário na consulta ele fechar a janela e passar o código para o campo text?

Comment: Fechar a janela depende da forma que você ta abrindo, script, framework e etc. Acho que seu botão close vai funcionar perfeitamente

Comment: Sobre pegar o código selecionado, estou colocando o script na resposta

Comment: Consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Considere um `input`:

```
<form>
  <label>
    Qual é o seu número da sorte?
    <input name="number" type="text" />
    <sub>Pressione <kbd>F2</kbd> para exibir a lista.</sub>
  </label>
</form>
```

Para verificar a tecla pressionada, utilize a função [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) do jQuery:

```
$("input[name=number]").keypress(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key == "F2")
    {
        // A tecla F2 foi presisonada.
    }
});
```

Para abrir uma nova janela, dependerá muito da lógica da sua aplicação. Como você não foi muito claro quanto ao problema, utilizei uma simples janela modal do Bootstrap CSS:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Número da Sorte</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="1" /> 1
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="2" /> 2
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="3" /> 3
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="4" /> 4
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="5" /> 5
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-save">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para exibí-la, basta:

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

Ficando, então:

```
$("input[name=number]").keypress(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key == "F2")
    {
        // A tecla F2 foi presisonada.
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Na janela modal, o usuário seleciona o valor desejado e clica no botão "Salvar". Quando este é clicado, atualizamos o valor do `input`:

```
$("#modal-save").on("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const value = $("input[name=my_number]:checked").val();
  $('#modal').modal('hide');
  $("input[name=number]").val(value);
});
```

O código completo, com um exemplo funcional, pode ser visto abaixo:

```js
$(() => {
  $("input[name=number]").keypress(event => {
    if (event.key == "F2")
    {
      $('#modal').modal('show');
    }
  });
  
  $("#modal-save").on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = $("input[name=my_number]:checked").val();
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
    $("input[name=number]").val(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <label>
    Qual é o seu número da sorte?
    <input name="number" type="text" />
    <sub>Pressione <kbd>F2</kbd> para exibir a lista.</sub>
  </label>
</form>

<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Número da Sorte</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="1" /> 1
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="2" /> 2
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="3" /> 3
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="4" /> 4
          <input type="radio" name="my_number" value="5" /> 5
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-save">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alterei o javascript para poder ler o F2, da forma com `onkeypress` que me passou não lê teclas que não geram caracteres, então alterei para keyup que lê teclas precionadas por codigo: `document.onkeyup=function(e){
   if(e.which == 113){
 $('#modal').modal('show');
   }
     $("#modal-save").on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = $("input[name=my_number]:checked").val();
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
    $("input[name=number]").val(value);
  });
}`

Comment: E o que quer dizer com isso?

Comment: Desculpe apertei enter sem querer. Já editei o comentário. Da forma que me passou acredito que vai dar certo, vou ter que agora criar uma consulta dinâmica dentro do modal. Achava que poderia ter uma função dentro biblioteca no jquery que faria isso.

Comment: Exato. Aqui funcionou, mas li que o comportamento pode variar conforme o navegador. Se o conteúdo da modal é dinâmico, pode utilizar requisições AJAX com jQuery mesmo para carregá-lo.

Comment: Sim vou fazer. Estranho que já vi em algum lugar funcionando com uma janela mais simples, como se fosse um jquery direto. Para achar o código de um produto simplesmente clicava F2, ele trazia uma janela tipo DatePicker do Jquery com todos produtos, e no campo de busca era só ir digitando e ele ia filtrando conforme a consulta, após 2 cliques ele passava o código para o campo text.

Comment: Se achar novamente, pode passar aqui o link que damos uma analisada em como foi feito.